# Installation script for python 2.7 in centos 5 without using internet.

Tags: linux, python, centos5

Is it possible to install python 2.7 without the internet in centos 5? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CentOS 5 is over 11 years old. Nobody should be using it for anything anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The responsible thing to do is to upgrade the OS, as CentOS 5 is end of life. Conveniently EL 7 defaults to Python 2.7.

If you will not upgrade the distro, first find the packages you want to install. (I don't have a recommendation because [the software collection for Python does not have a EL5 build.](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/)) You may present a yum repository to this system a couple ways: with removable media, or a connection to a local mirror that does have Internet.